# When the "context" attribute is specified, values of both "context" and "url" must start with "/"

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

When I try to access my application home URL `localhost:8080/CP/index.do` am getting the below stacktrace

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: In URL tags, when the "context" attribute is specified, values of both "context" and "url" must start with "/".
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:912)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:841)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.core.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:447)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service$glowroot$metric$http$request$7(HttpServlet.java:728)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:48)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service$glowroot$metric$http$request$7(HttpServlet.java:728)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:48)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:263)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet$glowroot$metric$http$request$0(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service$glowroot$metric$http$request$7(HttpServlet.java:728)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:48)

    root cause 
javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: In URL tags, when the "context" attribute is specified, values of both "context" and "url" must start with "/".
    org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.UrlSupport.resolveUrl(UrlSupport.java:152)
    org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.UrlSupport.doEndTag(UrlSupport.java:103)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.core.index_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005furl_005f0(index_jsp.java:491)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.core.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:175)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service$glowroot$metric$http$request$7(HttpServlet.java:728)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:48)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service$glowroot$metric$http$request$7(HttpServlet.java:728)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:48)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:263)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet$glowroot$metric$http$request$0(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service$glowroot$metric$http$request$7(HttpServlet.java:728)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:48)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
```

Here is my index.jsp file

```
input#username {
        background: #fff url(<c:url value='/core/v2/img/login_username.png' context='${ staticContext }' />) no-repeat 10px center;
        background-image: url(<c:url value='/core/v2/img/login_username_ie.png' context='${ staticContext }' />)\9;
        background-size: 15px 15px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    }
    input#password, input#certpassword {
        background: #fff url(<c:url value='/core/v2/img/login_password.png' context='${ staticContext }' />) no-repeat 10px center;
        background-image: url(<c:url value='/core/v2/img/login_password_ie.png' context='${ staticContext }' />)\9;
        background-size: 15px 15px;
        border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
        box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    }

<form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" method="post" action="j_spring_security_check" autocomplete="off">
        <fieldset>
            <c:if test="${pageContext.request.serverName ne 'cp.datacert.com' and pageContext.request.serverName ne 'collaborate.datacert.com'}">
                <div id="notProd"><spring:message code="nonproduction.environment.message" /> <c:out value="${pageContext.request.serverName}" /></div>
            </c:if>
            <img src="<c:url value='/core/v2/img/logo.png' context='${ staticContext }' />" width="175" height="155" />

            <c:if test="${ param.timeout ne null }">
                <div class="alert alert-info"><spring:message code="security.user.account.timeout" /></div>
            </c:if>
            <c:if test="${ (param.failedMessage != null && param.failedMessage != '') or failedMessage != null}">
                <div class="alert alert-error">
                    <c:choose>
                        <c:when test="${ param.failedMessage eq 'security.user.account.locked' }">
                            <spring:message code="security.user.account.locked" />
                        </c:when>
                        <c:when test="${ param.failedMessage eq 'security.user.account.expired' }">
                            <spring:message code="security.user.account.expired" />
                        </c:when>
                        <c:when test="${ param.failedMessage eq 'security.user.incorrect.password' }">
                            <spring:message code="security.user.incorrect.password" />
                        </c:when>
                        <c:when test="${failedMessage ne null}">
                            <spring:message code="${failedMessage}" />
                        </c:when>
                    </c:choose>
                </div>
            </c:if>

            <label>email address</label>
            <input type="text" name="j_username" id="username" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" placeholder="email address" title="email address" />
            <label>password</label>
            <input type="password" name="j_password" id="password" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" placeholder="password" title="password" />
            <button type="submit" onclick="this.disabled=true; this.form.submit.click();"><spring:message code="v2.login.button" /></button>
            <p id="link"><a href="forgotPassword.do"><spring:message code="index.login.forgotPassword"/></a></p>
            <!-- legacy support -->
            <div class="loginContent" style="display:none">
                <button type="submit" name="submit"><spring:message code="common.button.login" /></button>
            </div>

        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

I tried updating all the context values with prefix / as `context='/${ staticContext }'` but still am getting the same error. Can someone help me with my issue?

Comment: does it also fail if you hard-code context values with "/somePath"

Comment: I didnt try hard-code, let me try that...

Comment: staticContext value comes from database in our application and the value was `Passport` instead of `/Passport`, fixed it by changing it